htpdate daemon does not sync time with time server
I am debugging an issue where the time of my device does not sync with the time server. I have a script that first syncs the time with the time server and then starts an htpdate daemon, below is the script:
#!/bin/bash
# get rid of any htpdate process
killall htpdate
rm -rf /var/run/htpdate.pid

# Sync device time with time server
# -s : set time immediately
# -t : no sanity check
# -d : enable debug
htpdate -s -d -t some.time.server.com

# Start the htpdate daemon
# -D : start htpdate in daemon mode
# -a : adjust time smoothly
# -t : no sanity check
# -m : min poll interval (in seconds)
# -M : max poll interval (in seconds)
htpdate -D -d -a -t -m 60 -M 120 some.time.server.com

It is confirmed that the daemon is running since I can see it in ps:
4181 root      2200 S    htpdate -D -d -a -t -m 60 -M 120 some.time.server.com

And at first instance of running the script, the time is synced. There is only an offset of 0.750 seconds:
# htpdate -d -q -t some.time.server.com
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:33 GMT (439 ms) => 0
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:34 GMT (449 ms) => 0
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:35 GMT (427 ms) => 0
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:36 GMT (429 ms) => 0
when: 1000000000, nap: 62500000
offset: 0.000000
No time correction needed

Now, I run a script to change the time of the device. Offsetting it by 5 seconds. Here is the script:
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_TIME=$(date +%s)
echo $CURRENT_TIME
NEW_TIME=$((CURRENT_TIME - 5))
echo $NEW_TIME
NEW_DATE=$(date -d "@$NEW_TIME" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
echo $NEW_DATE
date -s "$NEW_DATE"

Checking the time offset with htpdate, it is observed that there is an offset.
# htpdate -d -q -t some.time.server.com 
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:57 GMT (370 ms) => -5
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:58 GMT (379 ms) => -6
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:22:59 GMT (448 ms) => -6
some.time.server.com         80, 04 Sep 2024 06:23:00 GMT (394 ms) => -6
when: 125000000, nap: -62500000
offset: 5.875000
Offset 5.875 seconds

What I expect is that since the daemon is expected to correct the time between 60s to 120s, the time will be in sync again after some time. But this is not the case, after overnight run of the device when I checked the time offset of the device the offset is still 5+ seconds.
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Timecheck: Offset 5.875 seconds
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Timecheck: Offset 5.000 seconds
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Timecheck: Offset 5.875 seconds
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Timecheck: Offset 5.875 seconds
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Timecheck: Offset 5.875 seconds

Above, I just ran a script to repeatedly call htpdate -d -q -t some.time.server.com .
I tried using the -p option of htpdate when starting the daemon but still the offset does not correct. Here is my command for running the daemon:
htpdate -D -d -a -t -p 500 -m 60 -M 120 some.time.server.com

Why do you use htpdate? NTP is the best practice.

This is currently running on an embedded device and due to resources, we opt to use htpdate.

...but doesn't making a TCP connection and parsing HTTP response require more resources than exchanging SNTP packets?
